# Humble Frozenbyte Bundle - Error when installing .run file

Tags: installation, 11.04, games

I just bought and downloaded the most recent Humble Indie Bundle, and I downloaded a .run file for one of the games. I set the file to executable with `chmod +x Trine.64.run` and then tried installing it with `sh Trine.64.run`

I am getting the following error: `Trine.64.run: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I'm on 11.04 64 bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to just double-click the file in Nautilus after changing the permission.

Comment: Oh, geez. After I changed the permissions I never thought to just try clicking the file. It installs now. Goodness I feel stupid lol.

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked! Trine is a great game. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you ant to run it from the commandline, just run "./Trine.64.run" without the quotes.  It's not a shell script, it's a binary file.